# Tableau: Distinct count of a field which occurs more than once

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field customer_id and I need to track the number of unique users and repeat users. For example the table is as below:

| customer_id |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 22 |
| 33 |
| 11 |
| 44 |
| 22 |

Here, the no. of unique users is 4 (11,22,33,44) and number of repeat users are 2 (11,22).

I am calculating unique users as COUNTD([customer_id]).

How can I calculate repeat users? It is basically the distinct count of the values which appear more than once. I tried with the following expression:

```
COUNTD(IF COUNT([customer_id]) > 1
THEN [customer_id]
END)
```

but I'm getting an error: *Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments comparisons or results in IF expressions*

How else can I calculate the repeat users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your filter needs, you can rely on LOD using FIXED/INCLUDE:

```
{ FIXED [Customer Id] : if sum({ FIXED [Customer Id] : COUNT([Customer Id])}) > 1 then 1 end }
```

Basically, in the inner LOD you count the occourrences, and then you just take in consideration records having 2+ (>1) of them:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative to Fabio's answer can also do the job.  Just create a calculated field

```
COUNT([customer id]) >1
```

and add this to filter shelf.

You can filter out false candidates to remove unique users and taking returning customers only.